# How to keep leading zero when importing a csv file in R?

Tags: r

When I write a `.csv` file from R where my group names start with a leading zero value, the leading zeros are maintained. However when I import the `.csv` the leading zeros are dropped and the group names are converted to integers. How can I keep the leading zero in my group names when I import a `.csv` file in R?

Example

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 3))
colnames(df)[1] <- 'site'
df$site <- c('01','02','03')
str(df) # the site name has a character class and the leading zeros are maintained
write.csv(df,'test.csv', row.names = FALSE) # I opened in notepad to verify that the leading zeros are maintained

df2 <- read.csv('test.csv')
str(df2) # the site name is integer class and leading zeros have been dropped
```

Comment: Try `identical( 0023,  23 )`.  There is no such thing as a leading zero is _numeric_ variable.  While you can _format it to text with leading zeros_ those drop when re-reading.  Unless you force a read `as,character`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the column as `"character"` .

```
read.csv("test.csv", colClasses = c(site = "character"))
##   site
## 1   01
## 2   02
## 3   03
```

If you don't have any other columns or if the other columns are also character this could be shortened to:

```
read.csv("test.csv", colClasses = "character")
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same as what I've written. Ok, you are using `read.csv`, but in general all the information is already included in my answer.

Comment: Both answer the question but this answer has more concise code, does it without introducing extra packages and uses precisely the setup in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Define the column type explicitly, for example using `vroom`. But other packages also provide that functionality.
You can determine the column specifications with `spec()` first.

```
library(vroom)
spec(vroom('test.csv'
             , delim = ","
             ))
df2 <- vroom('test.csv'
             , delim = ","
             , col_types = cols(
               site = col_character()
             )
             )
```